# Disable-Mailbox cmdlet from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I have created a C# Console Application that Creates/Deletes exchange accounts for a user. I have "Microsoft Server Exchange 2010" installed on the dev machine.
Psuedo code looks like:

```
public Runspace getRunspace()
{
    RunspaceConfiguration rsConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
    PSSnapInException snapInException;
    PSSnapInInfo snapinInfo = rsConfig.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010", out snapInException);
    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rsConfig);
    runspace.Open();
    return runspace;
}

public void createMailBox(string login)
{
    PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
    powershell.Runspace = getRunspace();
    PSCommand command = new PSCommand();
    command.AddCommand("Enable-Mailbox");
    command.AddParameter("Identity", login);
    command.AddParameter("Database", "Database01");
    powershell.Commands = command;
    powershell.Invoke();
    powershell.Dispose();
}

public void deleteMailBox(string login)
{
    PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
    powershell.Runspace = getRunspace();
    PSCommand command = new PSCommand();
    command.AddCommand("Disable-Mailbox");
    command.AddParameter("Identity", login);
    command.AddParameter("Confirm", false);
    powershell.Commands = command;
    try
    {
        powershell.Invoke();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    powershell.Dispose();
}
```

Issue is the createMailBox method creates exchange accouts without any issues, but deleteMailBox method doesn't disables the Exchange account and neither it throws any error/exception.

Problem I suspect is with the 'Confirm' parameter. I have tried

```
powershell.AddScript("Disable-Mailbox -Identity " + login + " -Confirm:$false")
```

But this ain't working either.

Comment: Have you tried the same from a powershell command line?

Comment: Yup I have tried that from the Exchange Management Console. It successfully deletes the mailbox

Comment: Command : Disable-Mailbox -Identity <login> -Confirm:$false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [error stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psdatastreams.error%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the existence of an error.

```
powerShell.Streams.Error
```

Comment: This is the message from powerShell.Streams.Error

**Active Directory operation failed on _Domain Controller_. This error is not retriable. Additional information: Insufficient access rights to perform the operation.
Active directory response: 00002098: SecErr: DSID-03150A48, problem 4003 (INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS), data 0**

Comment: The point I am not getting is, the same command works when directly executed from Exchange Management Console (PowerShell) but doesn't when tried through C#. Could it be something to do with the way we are initializing the Runspace?

Comment: I would think it would have more to do with user context. I think the runspace is fine. You're running as the same user in both cases (powershell vs C#)? Also, have you elevated either process?

Comment: for both the cases user is the currently logged in user so same, and I haven't elevated either of the processes.